# Cannot update the data using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Cannot update the data using async function updateCourse(id), any help?
I would like to update the isPublished and author properties by id.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises')
.then(() => console.log('Connected to mongodb...'))
.catch(error => console.error('Connection failed to mongoDB...', error))

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
tags: [String],
date: Date,
name: String,
author: String,
isPublished: Boolean,
price: Number,

});

const Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);

async function updateCourse(id) {

const course = await Course.findById(id);
if (!course) return;

course.isPublished = true;
course.author = 'Author Author';

const result = await course.save();
console.log(result);
}

updateCourse('5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e');
```

Comment: there is any stack trace? anyway I think you should call `updateCourse` after the connection to mongoose in the `.then(() => console.log('Connected to mongodb..`

Comment: Add the error message

Answer (score 0):

Documents returned from queries without the lean option are **MongooseDocuments**, not javascript plain objects. So you can't update them or use **save()**

```
const course = await Course.findOne({ _id: id }).lean();
if (!course) return;
course.isPublished = true;
course.author = 'Author Author';
course.save()
```

Why don't you use findOneAndUpdate

```
const updatedCourse = await Course.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      { $set: { isPublished: true, author: 'Author Author' }  })
```

Just use lean() and you are good to go...